# Erro no wordpres JQMIGRATE: Migrate is installed, version 1.4.1

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, wordpress, wordpress-theme

Esta aparecendo o erro JQMIGRATE: Migrate is installed, version 1.4.1 no meu site worpdress somente quando uso o navegador Google chrome. No mozila e no edge o site funciona normal e o efeito scroll tambem. Ja no chrome e no opera o efeito scroll nao funciona. Como resolvo o problema?
O site é: http://needeng.com.br/

Answer (score 1):

Não é um erro, é uma informação de que o WordPress está usando o script de migração do jQuery para assegurar a compatibilidade com versões anteriores.

Veja a resposta desta pergunta:
https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/224661/annoying-jqmigrate-migrate-is-in-console-after-update-to-wp-4-5

Comment: Porque a função scroll esta funcionando perfeitamente no mozilla firefox e no edge e no chrome e opera não? esta relacionado uai

Comment: É muito difícil apontar de quem é o problema em questões que envolvem o Wordpress visto que pode ser uma falha do seu template, um plugin recente que está com alguma incompatibilidade com outro plugin, ou ainda, a correção pode até está publicada na atualização de algum plugin, mas você pode estar com um cache desatualizado..